# Protractor test only testing some rows of Angular Grid

Tags: angular, protractor, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am trying to write a Protractor test to validate the text within each cell in the first row of an Angular Grid.

The Angular Grid has 299 rows, but only 30 rows are being tested for some reason.

I have removed some of the *Expected Results* & *error message* below to make it easier to read.

Protractor Code:

```
it('should validate the Spec column(first column) in the Table', () => {
        element.all(by.css('div.ag-cell[col-id="Spec"]'))
            .map(function (cell) {
                return cell.getText();
            })
            .then(function (cellValues) {
                expect(cellValues).toEqual(["2205", "2205", "2304", "2507", "254SMO", "26-4-4", "29-4", "302", "304", "304H", "304L", "304N", "305", "308", "309", "309S", "310",
                    "310S", "316", "316H", "316L", "316N", "317", "317L", "321", "321H", "329", "330", "347", "3RE60", "405", "409", "410", "410S", "420", "430", "440A", "440B", "440C", "44LN",
                    "654SMO", " 70/30 CuNi", "7Mo Plus", plus a lot more expected results]);
            })
    });
```

Error Message:

```
    Expected $.length = 30 to equal 299.
    Expected $[30] = undefined to equal '405'.
    Expected $[31] = undefined to equal '409'.
    Plus a lot more
```

Can someone please tell me why it's only picking up a few of the cells?

Below, you can see one of the rows that is appearing `undefined` has `col-id="Spec"` so I don't know why that isn't being picked up in the test

[image]

Note: I've inspected the cells not being picked up & they have `col-id="Spec"`.

Comment: Does the all 299 rows are visible in one time? Or need enter next page or scroll down to make the rest rows  are visible?  Protractor only return visible elements when it interacting with.

Comment: Hi @yong you would have to scroll down the Angular Grid to see the remaining results

Comment: If in such case, Protractor worked as designed.

Answer (score 0):

If you not strict on end to end (test case strict follow user experience), you can use `browser.executeScript()` to get all rows as following:

```
let _ = function(){
  cells = document.querySelectorAll('div.ag-cell[col-id="Spec"]')
  return Array.from(cells).map(function(cell){ return cell.textContent })
}

browser.executeScript(_).then(function(cellValues){
  expect(cellValues).toEqual(...)
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there a way to scroll down the angular grid also? As if a user scrolled to the bottom of the grid & saw all of the rows?

Comment: Also, is there a way you can apply this to my code above? I'm trying to apply it to the `map` within `element.all` but haven't been able to so far

Comment: Also, I replaced my code with yours above but am getting the same failure: `Expected $.length = 30 to equal 299.`

Comment: check the length of return NodeList by execute `document.querySelectorAll('div.ag-cell[col-id="Spec"]')` in browser devTool's console.  Or you can give an example page url online.